# Distance between turtle and a point in Python 2.x

Tags: python-2.7, turtle-graphics

I would like to get the distance between my turtle (which is a Vec2D) and a point ('a' which is also a Vec2D) I have seen ways to get the distance between two points like `dist = math.hypot(x2 - x1, y2 - y1)` but I want to know the distance without using the full coordinate.  Instead, I just want to use 't' and 'a' for my turtle and the point. Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: Why wouldn't you use the coordinates ? How can you tell the distance between two things if you do not know where they are ?

Comment: @Rafalon I do have the coördinates but it's not the same evry time I run my programme  so I can't fill those in

Comment: Aren't those coordinates stored in a variable/property you could use during runtime ? Like `t.x` or something ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your need correctly, you can use `t.distance(a)`.  The `.distance()` method of turtle is flexible in what it will accept as an argument (or arguments) per `help(turtle.distance)`:

```
distance(x, y)         # two coordinates
distance((x, y))       # a pair (tuple) of coordinates
distance(Vec2d)        # e.g. as returned by position()
distance(other_turtle) # distance to another turtle
```